# geemap-HTTPSConnectionPool error

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, geemap

I have faced a problem related to starting geemap applied on jupyter notebook framework in windows. while I have strived to solve this, no alternative has been found yet.

Can you guide me to overcome the issue?

The error is as follows:

> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='earthengine.google.com', port=443): Max
> retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to
> proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection
> object at 0x0000007E708813A0>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target
> machine actively refused it')))